# Why saveAsTextFile do nothing?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to implement simple WordCount in Scala + Spark. Here is my code

```
object FirstObject {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val input = "/Data/input"
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
                              .setMaster("spark://192.168.1.162:7077")
    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
    val text = sparkContext.textFile(input).cache()
    val wordCounts = text.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                         .map(word => (word,1))
                         .reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b)
                         .sortByKey()
    wordCounts.saveAsTextFile("/Data/output")

  }
```

This job is working for `54s`, and finally do nothing. Is is not writing output to `/Data/output`

Also if I replace `saveAsTextFile` with `forEach(println)` it is produce desired output.

Comment: just an idea: do you have set correct write rights to /data/output folder?

Comment: Shame on me! I moved it to `/tmp` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is a correct way, but I'll add this as an answer, so in future people could get answer in case if they will struggle with same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your user rights for /data/output folder. 
This folder should have writing rights for your specific user.